# Checking debug mode in C-code when call CreateLibrary with Debug -> True

Tags: external-calls, librarylink, c

I create a C-library and compile it using the tools in LibraryLink. When I create a code binary like this

```
CreateLibrary[src, "lib_name", "Debug" -> True]
```

I can specify the option `"Debug" -> True` or `False`. Is it possible to check the value of this option inside the C-code? I just want to add debug information if the library is compiled with Debug option and not use it if this option is not present. For example

```
//c-code

int is_debug(){
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
  return 1; //when Debug -> True
#else
  return 0; //when Debug -> False
#endif
}

//rest code
```

Comment: The precise ifdef to use would depend on the compiler that Mathematica is using, so check docs for whatever compiler you have set in `$CCompiler`. Usually `NDEBUG` or `DEBUG` is a good bet.

Comment: There are other ways of course: you could check for sections in the binary (on linux where DWARF info is embedded into the ELF), or for the presence of a PDB file next to it (if on windows), or you could assert(false) and drop to a signal handler immediately after you load the library and set a flag.

Comment: @flinty thanks! I tried both options and unfortunately there are no definitions for those names `DEBUG` and `NDEBUG`

Comment: I use visual studio compiler

Comment: "_DEBUG Defined as 1 when the /LDd, /MDd, or /MTd compiler option is set. Otherwise, undefined."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170